# Protect a second server behind existing OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have an existing Ubuntu server that denies all incoming traffic with a client unless it's able to authenticate with OpenVPN (we use Tunnelblick to manage client connections). However, we have other public servers (public IP addresses, not ones sat on a private VPN to be exposed) that we'd like to block access to using the same existing OpenVPN install.

Here's a subset from server.conf:

```
port 1194
dev tun
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route (new_machine_IP) 255.255.255.255"
```

From here, what's an appropriate way to disable public access to the new server if the visitor isn't authenticated behind the VPN? I've installed ufw and openvpn, but from here, I'm a bit worried that I'm either going to lock myself out by accident by closing public access before setting up the forwarding, or I'm going to just terribly mess up the forwarding in the first place.